# kdb: how to fill empty values of string column with previous value

Tags: string, null, kdb, fill

I have a table like this:

```
t:([] c1:1 0n 3 4;c2:("abcd";"efgh";"igkl";""))
c1 c2    
---------
1  "abcd"
  "efgh"
3  "igkl"
4  ""
```

I want to use the previous line to fill the empty values (including the empty string ""), the expected result is this:

```
c1 c2    
---------
1  "abcd"
1  "efgh"
3  "igkl"
4  "igkl"
```

I tried to do this with the function fills, but without success，

```
fills t
```

The content of the error is "length: Incompatible list lengths."
Thank you to those who can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a large table the below might be quicker than the other answers (with the caveat that it's a good deal more memory intensive than Sean's):

```
select {x (where l) -1+sums l:not x~\:""}[c2] from t
c2
------
"abcd"
"efgh"
"igkl"
"igkl"

q)t2:100000#t
q)\ts select {x (where l) -1+sums l:not x~\:""}[c2] from t2
2 3277952
q)\ts select {$[count y;y;x]}\[c2] from t2
11 1049888
```

This avoids the loop by creating a list of booleans showing where x is not empty.
We also get the actual indices of the non-empty values using `where`.
We can `sums` our boolean list to get a list of indices which we use to pull out only the required fill values from our original list.

Answer (score 2):

```
q)t:([] c1:1 0n 3 4;c2:("abcd";"efgh";"igkl";""))
q)select {$[count y;y;x]}\[c2] from t
c2
------
"abcd"
"efgh"
"igkl"
"igkl"
```

Answer (score -3):

You could do:

```
update string fills`$c2 from t
```

Character string are getting length error because each string are of different length.

Comment: This will blow the in memory sym heap, which cannot be freed until a restart

Comment: Yes, you are right if the table is a very large one like on a hdb then you should avoid casting char to syms like this. I was trying to explain the concept of using fills and why it caused an error.